# Pyomo: objective value in iterations is descresing in a maximization task

Tags: pyomo

I was using Pyomo to do a maximization task like this:

```
model.value = Objective(
        expr=model.z,
        sense=maximize)
SolverFactory("ipopt", executable="ipopt.exe").solve(model, tee=True)
```

but the objective values in the optimization are decreasing, which is pretty strange

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 2.4801658e+000 0.00e+000 1.79e+000  -1.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
   1 2.4515088e+000 0.00e+000 8.98e-001  -1.0 1.60e-001    -  4.24e-001 1.00e+000f  1
   2 1.6391697e+000 0.00e+000 2.69e+000  -1.0 1.63e+000    -  9.67e-001 8.34e-001f  1
   3 1.3639204e+000 0.00e+000 2.55e+000  -1.0 2.78e+001    -  3.41e-001 1.00e+000f  1
   4 5.2136288e-002 0.00e+000 4.65e+000  -1.0 9.41e+002    -  1.86e-001 1.48e-001f  1
   5 -3.7617049e-001 0.00e+000 2.76e+000  -1.0 1.11e+001  -2.0 1.34e-001 4.87e-002f  3
   6 -5.6000404e-001 0.00e+000 6.43e-001  -1.0 4.79e+001    -  9.16e-001 1.00e+000f  1
   7 -7.8784121e-001 0.00e+000 1.05e+000  -1.7 9.28e+001    -  1.01e-001 1.00e+000f  1
   8 -8.9977512e-001 0.00e+000 2.90e-001  -1.7 3.03e+001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
   9 -9.3095555e-001 0.00e+000 7.37e-002  -1.7 4.21e+001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
  10 -9.3836420e-001 0.00e+000 2.73e-002  -2.5 2.66e+001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  11 -9.4091425e-001 0.00e+000 1.22e-002  -3.8 2.21e+001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  12 -9.4130507e-001 0.00e+000 2.23e-003  -3.8 1.10e+001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  13 -9.4132835e-001 0.00e+000 1.01e-004  -3.8 2.51e+000    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  14 -9.4133170e-001 0.00e+000 2.66e-005  -5.7 1.32e+000    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  15 -9.4133171e-001 0.00e+000 4.35e-008  -5.7 5.33e-002    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
  16 -9.4133171e-001 0.00e+000 3.94e-009  -8.6 1.62e-002    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1

Number of Iterations....: 16

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............: -9.4133171247314817e-001  -9.4133171247314817e-001
Dual infeasibility......:  3.9385501166118218e-009   3.9385501166118218e-009
Constraint violation....:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Complementarity.........:  3.1027641313064256e-009   3.1027641313064256e-009
Overall NLP error.......:  3.9385501166118218e-009   3.9385501166118218e-009
```

additionally, the optimal objective value `-9.4133171247314817e-001` is inconsistent with the value given by the code `model.value()`, which is `0.736710908050222`.

Any ideas for these two issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most (maybe all?) solvers do "maximization" problems by just negating the expression for the objective and running minimization, which is the default internal behavior.  So if you are watching the steps, you may see decreasing values, and the final value should be the negative of the solution.

As far as why you are seeing something different...  Not totally clear from the info you posted and what framework you are using but:

1. Ensure the completion status is "optimal" or you may have junk
2. if you are using `pyomo` (the syntax fits) you should be using pyomo's value function:

---

```
pyo.value(model.obj)
```

or if you did a raw import of pyomo namespace (not recommended) then:

```
value(model.obj)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your hints. Now I totally understand the first issue. But regarding the second one, the objective value is also `0.736710908050222` using `value(model.obj)`. It is not the opposite of the optimal solution. Any ideas for this issue? Althought it shows `EXIT: Optimal Solution Found`, I'm sure this solution is still pretty far away from the optimum (~1.9).

Comment: well, I'm not overly experienced reading the streaming output...  maybe those are relaxations of some kind.  I would trust the output if the status is optimal.  If you think there is a better solution, try plugging in values.  ipopt is quite good.  I'd be surprised if it didn't get it.  Of course, if your problem has some very odd structure, it may miss a bit... NLP solutions don't usually have a universal guarantee of optimality.

Comment: https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OUTPUT.html

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I will go through with the ipopt documentation to get some solutions perhaps :)